# Having trouble passing in a dependent object to a Javascript Module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have the following code:

```
var myModule = (function($) {
  // Insert code here
} (jQuery || Zepto));
```

If I don't have jQuery referenced on the page, the script errors out saying that `jQuery is undefined.`  There's many times in code where I'll write `var foo = missingObj || fallbackObj;` and it works fine.

I'm trying to figure out a) why it doesn't work in this context and b) what an alternative would be since I would like to use this projects that use either framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var foo = missingObj || fallbackObj;`

only works if `missingObj` is not undeclared. For example. this happens when `missingObj` is an argument whose value is `undefined` (this is the most common use case for x = y || default)

The code your looking for is

`} (window.jQuery || window.Zepto));`

So basically the reason it doesn't work is because your confusing objects who have a value `undefined` and objects which are undeclared.

Accessing `jQuery` is accessing an undeclared value, which doesn't work. Accessing `window.jQuery` is accessing an undefined value, which does work.

For example

```
function jQuery(options) {
  options = options || {};
  ...
}
```

Works because `options` is undefined rather then undeclared

Comment: I was typing my answer thinking "Now, there's a way that's about a thousand times better, what is it again?" but I was drawing a blank. Turns out I could have just refreshed the page.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple.  Thanks!